# Get text content from an epub file flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, epub

I am trying to extract text content from an epub file but unable to do so. I have tried converting it to bytes and then read it but it's not returning a proper text. I can't find any library that helps me do so.
I only need the text file from the epub file so that I can read it with text to speech.

Comment: check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB and read `Implementation` section

Comment: it says: *"An EPUB publication is delivered as a single file. This file is an unencrypted zipped archive containing a set of interrelated resources"* so all you need is to unzip one file from a zipped epub file, you can find more info about zip related classes in [archive_io](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/archive_io/archive_io-library.html) library which comes with every flutter distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using the [epubx](https://pub.dev/packages/epubx/install) package

Here is the complete code

```
      File _epubFile = File(file.path);
      final contents = await _epubFile.readAsBytes();
      EpubBookRef epub = await EpubReader.openBook(contents.toList());
      var cont = await EpubReader.readTextContentFiles(epub.Content!.Html!);
      List<String> htmlList = [];
      for (var value in cont.values) {
        htmlList.add(value.Content!);
      }
      var doc = parse(htmlList.join());
      final String parsedString = parse(doc.body!.text).documentElement!.text;

      return parsedString;
```

Comment: For anyone who's wondering where `parse` is coming from, it's the html package and `import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;`